# Perl regex all entire next line to be stored into a variable (only the NEXT line)

Tags: regex, perl

My Perl script fetches a file log (created by Apache log4j), somehow the regex command `\.`  next line  is not storing the all entire row into a variable; it is working fine untill ErrorType my variable message is empty and `@nextline` should contain the all entire next line (any characters any letter any special signs).

I tried `\. (\D+\S+)`

Perl regex:

```
while (<$fh>) {
    my @fields = m{^
        (\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}\s\d{2}:\d{2}:[\d,]+)
        \s (INFO | INFO\s | VERBOSE) \s
        \[(?: SOAP | GUI )\s[(]User:["](\w+)",\sThreadId:\s\d+\)] 
        \s com.whatever.whichever.(\S+) \s \(\S+\.PYTHON\:\d+\) \s
        - (?! \sUser )   
        \s (\D+\S+) 
        \. (\D+\S+)   #the all entire next line
    $}x

    printf('$date=%s; $lovelforlogs=%s; $userid=%s; $methodused=%s; $Errortype=%s; $nextline=%s',@fields );

print "\n";
```

Example log entries:

```
2014-12-10 12:25:13,688 INFO [SOAP (User:"userid", ThreadId: 11)] com.whatever.whichever.program.cache (myMethod.PYTHON:59) - CRITICAL ERROR
; hereSometest#: 368; some other#: 23
at org.JBOSS.xpath.compiler.XPathParser.error(XPathParser.PYTHON:610)
    at org.JBOSS.xpath.compiler.XPathParser.initXPath(XPathParser.PYTHON:145)
    at org.JBOSS.xpath.XPath.<init>(XPath.PYTHON:227)
    at org.JBOSS.xalan.processor.StylesheetHandler.createXPath(StylesheetHandler.PYTHON:155)
    at org.JBOSS.xalan.processor.XSLTAttributeDef.processEXPR(XSLTAttributeDef.PYTHON:763)
    at org.JBOSS.xa
2015-01-21 12:23:51,681 INFO  [SOAP (User:"userid", ThreadId: 83)] com.whatever.whichever.program.cache (myMethod.PYTHON:690) - ERROR
com.whatever.whicever.program.exceptions.InvalidParameterException: F20176 VALUE is WRONG [G00097]
at org.JBOSS.xpath.compiler.XPathParser.error(XPathParser.PYTHON:610)
    at org.JBOSS.xpath.compiler.XPathParser.initXPath(XPathParser.PYTHON:145)
    at org.JBOSS.xpath.XPath.<init>(XPath.PYTHON:227)
    at org.JBOSS.xalan.processor.StylesheetHandler.createXPath(StylesheetHandler.PYTHON:155)
    at org.JBOSS.xalan.processor.XSLTAttributeDef.processEXPR(XSLTAttributeDef.PYTHON:763)
    at org.JBOSS.xa
2015-01-27 12:24:37,079 VERBOSE [SOAP (User:"userid", ThreadId: 70)] com.whatever.whichever.program.cache (myMethod.PYTHON:2066) - Unchecked error
AxisFault
at org.JBOSS.xpath.compiler.XPathParser.error(XPathParser.PYTHON:610)
    at org.JBOSS.xpath.compiler.XPathParser.initXPath(XPathParser.PYTHON:145)
    at org.JBOSS.xpath.XPath.<init>(XPath.PYTHON:227)
    at org.JBOSS.xalan.processor.StylesheetHandler.createXPath(StylesheetHandler.PYTHON:155)
at org.JBOSS.xalan.processor.XSLTAttributeDef.processEXPR(XSLTAttributeDef.PYTHON:763)
at org.JBOSS.xa
```

Result should be:

```
date=2014-12-10 12:25:13,688 lovelforlogs=INFO userid=userid methodused=myMethod Errortype=CRITICAL ERROR message=; hereSometest#: 368; some other#: 23
date=2014-12-10 12:25:13,688 lovelforlogs=INFO userid=userid methodused=myMethod Errortype=ERROR ERROR message=com.whatever.whicever.program.exceptions.InvalidParameterException: F20176 VALUE is WRONG [G00097]
date=2015-01-27 12:24:37,079 lovelforlogs=VERBOSE userid=userid methodused=myMethod Errortype=Unchecked error message=AxisFault
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There's a flaw with your logic here - you're doing `while ( <$fh> )` but that works one line at a time. So no regular expression can match. Similarly - if you're wanting to use multi-line regular expressions - you need to specify that in the flags.

From [perldoc perlre](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html):

> m
>
> Treat string as multiple lines. That is, change "^" and "$" from matching the start of the string's first line and the end of its last line to matching the start and end of each line within the string.
>
> s
>
> Treat string as single line. That is, change "." to match any character whatsoever, even a newline, which normally it would not match.
>   Used together, as /ms, they let the "." match any character whatsoever, while still allowing "^" and "$" to match, respectively, just after and just before newlines within the string.

(But well done on using lexical filehandles and `x` to specify your RE - that makes it lots clearer)

Following on from comments - whilst `while` is per line, you could cheat - if you're sure you definitely only want 'next line' when the pattern matches - grab it separately.

How about instead:

```
while ( <$fh> ) {
    my @fields = #pattern;
    my $next_line = <$fh>;
    #etc.    
}
```

Comment: i have no way to do it with the while? See every line i am reading i am also inserting into a DB ... so at the moment i can literally get all the errors correclty but i cannot store the message of the error...if I want to catch ABSOLUTELY EVERYTHING after a specific flag how do i do it? with \.?

Comment: Letssay i hade a line like this 2014-12-10 12:25:13,688 INFO [SOAP (User:"userid", ThreadId: 11)] com.whatever.whichever.program.cache (myMethod.PYTHON:59) - CRITICAL ERROR ; hereSometest#: 368; some other#: 23
  and i wanted to catch EVERYTHING ELSE UNTIL THE END OF THE LINE could i use simply \D+\S+ or \. ???

Comment: Either you can read `<$fh>` again to get the next line. If you want to grab everything between two patterns, you can use a range operator.

Comment: `(.*)$` will capture 'everything else until end of line' but not necessarily if you're doing multiline patterns, which is part of the problem here.

Comment: `\D+\S+` will capture one or more non digits, followed by one or more non spaces. That probably won't do what you want.

Comment: i tried to use your implementation but I quiet do not get the way i meant to do it?


while ( <$fh> ) {
    my @fields = #pattern;
    my $next_line = <$fh>;
    #etc.    
}